# Does sync s3 to s3 works in s3cmd version 1.1.0-beta3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

Does sync s3 to s3 works in s3cmd version 1.1.0-beta3 ?

```
# s3cmd --version
s3cmd version 1.1.0-beta3
```

Getting following error :

```
# s3cmd sync --exclude 'reportTemplate/*' 'orders/*' 'customers/*' s3://xxx-storage-bucket-prod-env/ s3://xxxx-storage-bucket-test-env/

ERROR: Parameter problem: Expecting filename or directory instead of: s3://inksedge-app-file-storage-bucket-prod-env/
```

Comment: These days it is recommend to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`. It also has an `aws s3 sync` command.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein will syntax be same for aws s3 syn ie  aws s3 sync  --exclude 'reportTemplate/*' 'orders/*' 'customers/*' s3://xxx-storage-bucket-prod-env/ s3://xxxx-storage-bucket-test-env/

Comment: $ aws s3 sync --exclude 'reportTemplate/*' 'orders/*' 'customers/*'  s3://inksedge-app-file-storage-bucket-prod-env   s3://inksedge-app-file-storage-bucket-test-env
Unknown options: s3://inksedge-app-file-storage-bucket-prod-env, s3://inksedge-app-file-storage-bucket-test-env
fabricapp@Inksedge-Bastion-01:~/Fabric$ aws s3 sync  s3://inksedge-app-file-storage-bucket-prod-env   s3://inksedge-app-file-storage-bucket-test-env --exclude 'reportTemplate/*' 'orders/*' 'customers/*'
Unknown options: orders/*, customers/*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) can also do bucket-to-bucket transfers of selected directories:

```
aws s3 sync s3://source-bucket s3://dest-bucket --exclude "*" --include "folder1/*" --include "folder2/*"
```

The `--exclude` parameter says don't copy anything, while the `--include` parameters add selected files/paths to copy.

See: [AWS CLI `S3 sync` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Answer (score 1):

s3cmd 1.1.0-beta3 is known to have many bugs, since fixed in 1.5.2 and newer.

https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/wiki/Common-known-issues-and-their-solutions